# permuted Monitor results after a screenshot

Tags: python

My Code should grab me a screenshot from one of my Monitors. The expected result is to get an Image of the second screen but what i get is a screenshot from the first Monitor. 
(the same happens if i try to get a screenshot of the first Monitor then i just get a one from the second screen)
I've already checked the screen Settings (Windows 7) and verified and identified which screen is the first and which one is the second. Can anyone explain this to me ? thanks in Advance.

```
from mss import mss
import cv2
with mss() as sct:
    filename = sct.shot(mon=2, output='screenshot.png') 
    img_bgr = cv2.imread('screenshot.png')
    cv2.imshow('image', img_bgr)
```

expected output: Screenshot of monitor 2

actual Output: Screenshot of monitor 1

Comment: try `mon = sct.monitors[2]`

Comment: thnx for your comment. Unfortunatly it leads to the same results. If I try the Code on an other Computer, it seems to work properly, that's why I think it's a Setting Problem, but i have no clue how to solve it.